# Distance between element and window updated when scrolling

Tags: jquery

How to make the distance from the div element and the bootom of the browser update itself?

Here's my part of the code which calculates the distance from the element to the bottom of the window. It works fine despite the fact that the values are not updated when user scrolls. Lets assume that there are several blocks and I need to know whether any of these is getting close to the window edge. As I mentioned before, this calculates the distance onload but I need it to update the values if user scrolls the page. Any ideas?

```
var the_height = $(window).height(); // viewport height
var activeimage = $(this);  // div element
distanceBottom = the_height - activeimage.offset().top + activeimage.height();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEDMs/7/)

And now, since the fiddle is also here, my need for the distance value is because I want to make sure the tooltip is within visible area. My original idea was to move make the tooltip position above the thumb if thumb is realy close to the edge. Thats where the distance is needed

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your code within window.scroll event and it will be called every time the document is scrolled. If you put it in the document onload event, it is called once and hence not updated  after that.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var the_height = $(window).height(); // viewport height
    var activeimage = $(this);  // div element
    distanceBottom = the_height - activeimage.offset().top + activeimage.height();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Not sure, if I understand your requirement correctly. Is commenting out the function definitions help? I also don't see any usage of the distanceBottom variable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('div.thumbnail-item').mouseenter(function(e) {

        contents = $(this).find('.tooltip').find('.invisible').html();
        tooltip = $(this).find('.tooltip').find('img');
        wholetooltip = $(this).find('.tooltip');
        var activeimage = $(this);  // div element

        tooltip.attr('src', contents);
        //$(window).scroll(function () { 
        var the_height = $(window).height(); // viewport height
        distanceBottom = the_height - activeimage.offset().top + activeimage.height();
        //});


        if (tooltip[0].complete) { // if image already loaded
            tooltipWidth = wholetooltip.width();
            tooltipHeight = wholetooltip.height();

            imgwidth = activeimage.width();
            imgheight = activeimage.height();

            test = 0 - tooltipHeight + imgheight; // will position nice without gray border


            activeimage.css('z-index','999')
        .children("div.tooltip")
        .css({'top': test,'left': imgwidth + 30,'display':'block'});



        } else { // if image not loaded
        tooltip.load(function() {

            imgwidth = activeimage.width();
            imgheight = activeimage.height();
            test = activeimage.offset().top - activeimage.offset().top - imgheight;

            activeimage.css('z-index','999')
        .children("div.tooltip")
        .css({'top': test,'left': imgwidth + 30,'display':'block'});



            tooltip.css({
            'border-color': 'red',
            'border-width': '5px'
            });
        });
        }



    }).mouseleave(function() {

        // Reset the z-index and hide the image tooltip 
        $(this).css('z-index','10')
        .children("div.tooltip")
        .animate({"opacity": "hide"}, "fast");
    });

});
```

Comment: This works but I have mousover function which does certain things and if I put the scroll function inside the distanceBottom variable is not accesible anymore. On the other hand I cant wrap wverything with the scroll function because this will fire whenever scrolled. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you mean "distanceBottom inside the scroll function" not "scroll function inside the distanceBottom". Declare the distanceBottom variable out of the window.scroll function(globally) and it will be accessble from everywhere.

Comment: I have added the whole code. What I want to achieve is to count the distance of the div and the browser bottom whenever that div has mouse over. The code above does all the stuff but the distance needs to be updated whenever pade is scrolled...

Comment: Updated the code a bit. It should calculate the distance every time you mouseover the div. What is the usage of distanceBottom variable?

Comment: the distanceBottom variable is to be used later on but since it does not update on scroll there was no point in writing more code. The idea is simple: whenever div has mouse over it I want to be able to get the divs distance from the bottom. If the mouse goes out and the user scrolls the page and mouse over back, the distance should get updated

Comment: So you are not getting dynamic values for distanceBottom variable when you mouse over the div? Does declaring the distanceBottom variable just under the document.ready and taking the window function out of the mouseenter function help?

Comment: I can't declare the distanceBottom variable outside the mouseenter function since it depends on the div which mouse is moved over. Generally the whole thing should work without the scroll function at all cause everything is set and retrieved within the mouseenter function. This means that whenever I mouse over a div, its position should be adequate even if I scroll the page, the div moves and I mouse over it again.